# How to rewrite query params and redirect site in varnish

Tags: regex, varnish

I'm looking to use varnish to rewrite the query param for this site and redirect the domain also

```
http://www.example.com/?s=SearchTerm ==> http://www.example2.com/search?q=SearchTerm
```

So far I've tried to get the first part ie. query params to rewrite using regsub ie.

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.http.host == "example.com") {
    set req.http.url = regsub(
    req.url,
        "^/?s=.*",
        "^/?search=.*"
    );
    set req.backend = www01;
    return (pass);
    }
 }
```

however the original url doesn't change in the varnishlog - anyone see the issue?

Cheers

Comment: why that will be changed? you only do this to modify the request sent to backend

Comment: apologies - I mean the varnishlog not the browser - Im writing out a std.syslog before and after on req.http.url and its unchanged after I regsub

Comment: [official refer](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/RedirectsAndRewrites) doesn't to have `set req.http.rul` but `set req.url`, try that.

Comment: See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gE0eE6/1),`\?\w+=(\w+)(?:&|$)`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue with obsolete code got from the web.
You need to replace

> set req.backend = www01;

by

> set req.backend_hint = www01;